# Reduce C++ source by variable substitution and dead code truncation?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have some template classes with Nontype parameters.

```
template <int hi, int wid>
class SomeThing {
...
}
```

I need to create a tool to reduce this source with given value of `hi` and `wid`, say, `hi=2; wid=3`. Sequentially, there might be some code becomes dead code, and the tool also needs to truncate them away. So, finally I expect to see a reduced source code as the output of the tool. Is there any known way to do this? A harder way may be to create my own c++ parser... sounds terrible even a simplified one.

I know there are tools like gcc-xml and clang which can parse it and give an easy-to-parse intermediate file. However, it looks like that it's not enough for me to regenerate c++ source file from that.

[EDIT]
A whole picture is to create a tool to generate source code from source code, with variable substitution and dead code truncation.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Usually templates just get expanded by the compiler during compilation.

Comment: Note that the compiler won't generate any machine code from template code that you don't use.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to reduce this source" and "I expect to output a reduced source code"? Do you want to generate C++ source code? Or do you want the code generated by the compiler to be reduced?

Comment: The purpose is to produce some smaller sample source code from a large source pool by giving the template parameter values. Intentionally someone don't want to expose the whole sources in the pool.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example of what are your inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Templates are not macros. Macros could be preprocessed. Templates cannot - and need not. Any reason you dislike angle brackets?

Comment: why don't you want to "expose the whole sources in the pool"?

Comment: @Shep, someone think it's sensitive data and simply don't want the user to see it.

Comment: But I assume you don't have the option to distribute just the binary? As @classdaknok_t noted, no machine code will be built from templates that aren't used.

Comment: @Shep Binary (obj files) are not eligible because there are so many different archs over there. Besides, the template parameter values are determined by user when they use it, not when we release it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I quite understood your question, but would template specialization answers your needs?

```
template<>
class SomeThing<2, 3> {
    //trimmed content
};
```

If you instantiate `SomeThing` with the value 2 and 3, the specialization will be chosen by the compiler and the generated executable will contain only the "truncated" content.

---

**Edit**:

Based on your edit, I suspect that you'd like to have a [partial evaluator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) for C++, meaning a program which takes a program and some of its inputs, and generates a specialized version of the program where all that could be evaluated had been evaluated.

I'm not aware of any existing implementations for native C++; however, you can find partial evaluators for many functional languages, but also for Pascal and C. Some works have been done to create a partial evaluator for the .Net bytecode (MSIL), which could be used to partially evaluate C++/CLI. [[Chepovsky et al. 2003](http://www.springerlink.com/content/r4rr30ajjn449q1a/)]

The C++ template mechanism can be seen as a limited kind of partial evaluation, since the compiler generates code specialized (and potentially partially evaluated) with the template parameters. However, all this is performed by the compiler internally, there is no intermediary C++ source code that you could visualize. However, you can have a look at the generated assembly code, which gives you a good idea of the operations/evaluations/optimizations performed by the compiler during template instantiation.

Comment: Agreed, it looks like he wants partial evalution.  He needs a full C++ parser, a set of bound values to instantiate, and something that can do constant folding on syntax trees and then regenerate valid C++ code from the resulting tree.  Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit and its C++11 front end could be used to build one of these (www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).   Likely to be a fair amount of work, because it has to include essentially all the C++ execution rules; might get by with less if he doesn't need squeakily simplified code.

Comment: ... on consideration, it may just be that he wants to protect his source code and yet have it be compilable by the customer.   In that case, a C++ source code obfuscator may be all he needs.  [We have those off the shelf.]

Comment: @Baxter: Thank you for the info. Yes I think the primary goal is to protect the source code. One quick question: will eliminating the dead code or not make any difference in terms of obfuscation?

Comment: @solotim: Obfuscation doesn't change what is dead.  If the compiler is any good, it will see dead code regardless of obfuscation and simply remove it as it compiles.

Comment: @Baxter: Yes. But what I want to ask is if reserving the dead code will make the obfuscated code more difficult to recognize/reverse-engineer. Or, it doesn't matter?

Comment: @solotim:  Its harder to reverse engineer something that contains useless nontrivial clues. If you have a choice, provide lots of useless dead code, as well as the useful part, all in obfuscated form.   Making things dead is interesting: "dead by no direct named reference" is sort of easy to handle (because there's no references).  "Dead because cannot be called via indirection, in spite of its address being taken a lot" is much tougher to determine, so if you can add that its a good idea.  Mainly if you have a fair amount of code, the obfuscator makes it hard enough.

Comment: @Baxter: Thank you very much. Your comments make a lot sense to me. I'll think about an appropriate solution. (DMS seems very powerful but it seems not good to misuse of good materials for minor purposes)

Answer (score 1):

There's no clean way to do this, as template code is generally Turing-complete.

As a very simple example, consider

```
template<int I>
class X : public X<I/2>
{
};
```

Now say that you want to reduce this for `I==351`. What exactly should be the base classes be? For real-world code you will need a full C++ compiler. Worse, you will also need a matching standard library implementation, and one that is fully representative of all compliant standard library implementations (!!)

Consider the following code:

```
template <int I>
class X : public std::vector<X<I/2> >
{
  // Methods
};
```

Dead code elimination will depend on the implementation of `std::vector`. If your implementations differ, you can accidentily eliminate code that is in fact needed.

Comment: Thanks for your concerns. My case doesn't go that far, but you reminded me to consider more about the solution. +1